# JavaFX tab header text could not align center

Tags: javafx, tabs, alignment

I am using .tab-pane .tab {} to change tab header color and width. This has no problem.

```
.tab-pane .tab
{
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, repeat, #CCCCCC , #808080 );
    -fx-pref-width: 150.0;
    -fx-text-alignment: CENTER;  <-- does not work
}
```

However, the text alignment has no effect, how do I do this?

Comment: For a general description of what `-fx-text-alignment` does, see the documentation for `textAlignmentProperty` in [`Labeled`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textAlignmentProperty). (Also note that a `Tab` is not a `Labeled`, so it doesn't have this property.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a look on [modena.css](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470) searching for the TabPane you will find out that the tab-label alignment is already by default to the CENTER but you have change the width of the .tab to 150.0 although the label width is still the same. So you need to specify the alignment and the width to the tab's label as well like this :

```
.tab-pane .tab
{
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, repeat, #CCCCCC , #808080 );
    -fx-pref-width: 150.0;
}

.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab > .tab-container > .tab-label {
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
     -fx-pref-width: 150.0;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;
}
```